# dust.js filter json result

Tags: javascript, templates, client-side, dust.js

i have the following json

```
         var tt =   projects: [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "amount": "10"
            }, {
                "name": "B",
                "amount": "20"
            }, {
                "name": "C",
                "amount": "30"
            }
        ]
```

with dust.js template engine, is there a way to use this json and filter through to only render project with the name B?

i thought a dust helper {@if cond="{projects.name} == 'B' "}...  could do it but i cannot make it work?

anyone has any ideas? any jsfiddle would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the `@eq` helper:

```
{#projects}
    {@eq key=name value="B"}
        My name is {name} and my amount is {amount}.
    {/eq}
{/projects}
```

This template will loop through each of the project items, but it will only print out:

```
My name is B and my amount is 20.
```

For this to work, you must have both [dustjs](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs) and [dustjs-helpers](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers) available.

Comment: You're welcome. It is customary on stackoverflow to accept the answer that works (as an indication to other users that the answer solved your problem) by clicking on the checkmark.